# How to implement an outgoing user provisioning from Azure Cloud to an external system

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-webapps

I need a process / programming / tool to have an automatic process, everytime a new user was created in a group or a user was changed (surname, givenname etc) I need to transfer this user object informations (username, surname, givenname, e-mail) to an external system to update the user there.
I didn´t found any good solution, I watch out for Azure Automate, Azure Graph API, Subscription model but no good idea to handle this.
Does anybody have any idea to get a trigger or listener on an Azure Object (group) for any changes and send this changes to an external system?

Comment: Find an existing trigger which reports changes of the group, but I haven't found it. Write a scheduled task to find out the updating of the groups, but it requires lots of code and it's not real-time. Write a entrance for your users to update groups via graph api, and you can send changing information programmatically, the shortage is that you can't receive the information of changing uses in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Graph include a Group delta query, which you could run periodically to pick up changes to the group.

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups

A potential architecture could to be have an Azure Function execute the REST API query to monitor for group changes, place any changes found into an Azure Storage Queue, and have your external system monitor the Azure queue for new user messages and take action.